Redirect NTP response with pfSense
As stated in the title I want to redirect the ntp response of a server. My first approach was simply to configure it with iptables. So every packet with the source port 123 is redirected to netfilterqueue, so a script can pick it up. I've noticed that the packet is just switched inside my host machine towards a Wi-Fi AP.
I corrected my approach by adding a firewall rule, which changes the default gateway to a OVS. So I learned that this is also wrong, since the pfSense is a stateful firewall, the packet belongs to an open state -> no firewall rules are applied.
Fine, so I added NAT rules inside my pfSense firewall, which should be implied before anything else. Since this is also not working I am wondering what else am I missing to finally intercept those responses.
Any help and tips are appreciated.

With iptables, the rule could look as simple as iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1. How do you have netfilterqueue configured?

pretty similar: iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --sport 123 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
Then inside my script I bind it to the specified queue. I am pretty sure that netfilterqueue is not the problem, since this worked already. Just not when I try to intercept incoming packets.
